# How to import old settings/repositories

Tags: git, smartgit

I am new in using Git/Smartgit. Now I had to configure a new PC under WIN 10. Could you please tell me, how I can export/import the settings and the repositories from the old PC to the new PC?

Thank you very much, regards,

Bernd

Comment: Consider accepting the answer, if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

SmartGit saves all its settings under `%appdata%\syntevo\SmartGit\<version>\`. Copy it from your old PC to your new PC. You are interested in `.xml` files only.

Comment: Not all. Some are in <user folder>\.gitconfig file.

Comment: This caused some problems in my case. Had to take back. Unfortunutely had to downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://smartgit.userecho.com/en/communities/1/topics/299-importexport-smartgit-settings I would say the best way I can find for now is to
Go to Help > About SmartGit > Information > Settings Path then click the folder icon to get to the suitable folder. You'll most likely want to highest version number folder based. Then the settings seem to be in yml files.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want grouping and repositories, you just need to copy from %appdata%\syntevo\SmartGit<last version you see> the following files:

- preferences.yml (external tools configuration, git command folder location,etc...)
- repositories.yml (name and folders of repos)
- repository-grouping.yml (name and repo grouping, if you had some)
- ui-config.yml (toolbar & gui customizations)